# Display joomla component within another component

Tags: joomla

I have a two components I am trying to integrate.

I created an new view in component #1,

I would like to iframe or load content from component #2.

The iframe works well once I have added 'tmpl=component', but well I click a link in the iframe. joomla includes the joomla footer and header.

Is there an efficient way to load content from component #2 into component #1?

I do not have access to the joomla template. I only have access to component #1 and #2.

Thanx.

Comment: I was trying to edit your question, but paragraph #4 makes no sense.  Please clarify.

Comment: I do not get what you want your want clarified. Can you please point out where you do not get the sense?

Comment: What do you mean here: `but well I click a link in the iframe. joomla includes in footer and header.`

Comment: Add 'tmpl=component' to every link in component #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an iframe is not the best option, you would be better off invoking the model of the other component from your main component's controller and handle the views from the main component.  So the double component would only exist in your backend logic, and the views would be completely handled by the main component alone.

This will work only if the secondary component's developer refrained from using JPATH_COMPONENT or other constants that would point to the wrong component.

To make an example, in your controller or main component's model:

```
$com_path = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_secondary_component/models';
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath($com_path , 'SecCompPrefixModel');
$secondaryModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'modelName', 'SecCompPrefixModel' ,array('ignore_request' => true));
```

... then you can use $secondaryModel->getItems() or the like, so your secondary component's items would be available in your main component.